# Pop Culture: My name with just one letter replaced

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay

Happy Independence Day to you American users, here is a puzzle to provide some entertainment on this fine Saturday. Once each clue is solved, there will be a final answer that they all share in common!

> 1. My name with just one letter replaced.
> 2. Just don't freak out.
> 3. I am fragile, okay!
> 4. My wet dog keeps doing this after a bath.
> 5. Could you repeat that for me?
> 6. I already realized you were not peaceful.
> 7. ______.
> 8. I am not going to freeze your photo.
> 9. Not ugly.
> 10. Now you've made me wet my job equipment.
> 11. It's not you.
> 12. Rhymes with sad crud.
> 13. Forward to January.
> 14. Not a dark horse.
> 15. Salutations from the Empire state.

I have added five more lines to the riddle to help! :)

Comment: I'm slightly confused, do we have to solve each line and itll lead us to another answer, or find the words and reconstruct the crossword?

Comment: Yes, each line has something in common, that is the big answer. You do not have to reconstruct it into a crossword, I thought it would be too easy if I constructed an actual crossword puzzle, so I just gave the clues! :)

Comment: You're sure these are normal crossword clues? Generally, crossword clues are direct synonyms for their answers - they should match in part of speech and tense/pluralization. (The usual rule is that it should be possible to replace the answer with the clue in a reasonable sentence.) A lot of these seem very vague, and I don't think that even if I got the answer I'd be sure of it.

Comment: I edited it to avoid any confusion. Now they are just regular clues!

Comment: Vf gur jbeq funxrf (funcrf (bar yrggre ercynprq))? @Crozier

Comment: @JohnBrookfields Abg dhvgr, gel gb fbyir rnpu bs gur yvarf vaqvivqhnyyl jvgu n fvzcyr nafjre, gura gurer jvyy or n pbzzbanyvgl nzbat gurz.

Comment: There's probably someone sharper than I am but for me, this puzzle seems a bit underspecified. I think maybe if you add enumerations, it will be easier/more solvable?

Comment: @Sid I added a pop culture category in the title to help narrow it down. It could be it is harder for this audience to solve? Haha I showed it to my younger sister and she solved it pretty quickly!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These clues all point towards:

> The titles of **songs by Taylor Swift**

As follows:

> 1. My name with just one letter replaced. **CRAZIER** (OP's name is 'Cr**o**zier')
>  2. Just don't freak out. **YOU NEED TO CALM DOWN**
>  3. I am fragile, okay! **DELICATE**
>  4. My wet dog keeps doing this after a bath. **SHAKE IT OFF**
>  5. Could you repeat that for me? **BEGIN AGAIN**
>  6. I already realized you were not peaceful. **I KNEW YOU WERE TROUBLE**
>  7. ______. **BLANK SPACE**
>  8. I am not going to freeze your photo. **PICTURE TO BURN**
>  9. Not ugly. **GORGEOUS**
>  10. Now you've made me wet my job equipment. **TEARDROPS ON MY GUITAR**
>  11. It's not you. **ME!**
>  12. Rhymes with sad crud. **BAD BLOOD**
>  13. Forward to January. **BACK TO DECEMBER**
>  14. Not a dark horse. **WHITE HORSE**
>  15. Salutations from the Empire state. **WELCOME TO NEW YORK**

<sub>In case you're interested, the breakthrough for me finally came with Clue 12, coupled with your throwaway comment to @Sid saying that your younger sister solved it pretty quickly!</sub>

Comment: You are correct! Nice job!! Haha I wasn't sure if the answer entertained too small of an audience or not! @Stiv